# Accessing to a parent's variable

Tags: django, inheritance, django-class-based-views

I have two class-based views that inherit from Base class:

```
class Base(object):
    context_object_name = "book_list"
    model = Book
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Book, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
    def get_queryset(self):
       book_set = Book.objects.all()
       return book_set

class C1(Base ,ListView):
    paginate_by = 20 
    template_name = 'sl/v1.html'

class C2(Base, View):
    template_name = 'sl/v2.html'
```

I need to do some process on the queryset result inside of C2 class. So how can I access to book_list in C2?

Answer (score 0):

```
class C2(Base, View):
    template_name = 'sl/v2.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super(C2, self).get_queryset()
        # do something

        return qs
```